# HTML form returns PHP script instead of success message

Tags: php, html, forms

There is an html form which I want to store data from in a database. After filling the form, it returns the php script instead of success message. And no data is getting stored in the database. Can you please help?

```
    <?php
if (isset(['submit'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
}
if (!empty($username) || !empty($password) || !empty($gender) || !empty($email) {
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbUsername = "root";
    $dbPassword = "";
    $dbname = "cakeshop";

    $conn = new mysqli($host, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbname);

    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        die('Connect Error('. mysqli_connect_error().)')'. mysqli_connect_error());
    }else {
        $SELECT = "SELECT email From register Where email = ? Limit 1"
        $INSERT = "INSERT INTO register (username, password, gender, email) values(?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($SELECT);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($email);
        $stmt->store_result();
        $rnum = $stmt->num_rows;

        if ($rnum==0){
            $stmt->close();

            $stmt = $conn->prepare($INSERT);
            $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $username, $password, $gender, $email);
            $stmt->execute();
            echo "New record inserted successfully"
        }else {
            echo "Someone already registered";
        }
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: share Json format data,,   return response()->json('New record inserted successfully', 422);

Comment: What is the URL of the html form ?

Comment: Are you missing   $_POST on line 2,

`if (isset(['submit'])) {`

And What script is getting in return?